How can I create an extension to automatically insert images into my flashcards on Quizlet?
I created numerous Quizlet flashcards but lacked time to include images. Despite attempting extensions and other methods, I was unsuccessful. Is there a method for me to develop a tool or an extension for this purpose? Which programming language should I use for this task?
I searched for extensions and methods on YouTube to help me with that. I hope to find a way to help me code a software or extension that can assist me in achieving that goal.

I'm guessing you're looking to build a Chrome extension. Do you already know how to code with Javascript, HTML and CSS?

I have no programming language knowledge. Still, I wish to create an extension to make Quizlet flashcards efficient. Which programming language would be the most suitable to start with?

It would be helpfull if you show up some examples

I've just written a simple TamperMonkey script to fill the first image of searching each card as the image for it. You can check here Gist. To better use, you should install the extension first and then inject this script. Or you can F12 and paste it in the console tab in browser

Linky-only answers are not good answers - Unsure why you are reposting the same answer after it's been deleted - Please have a look at How to not be a spammer
